# Solving a differential equation (Lattice Laplacian)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, random-walk

Suppose that $ p_n(t) $ is the probability of finding n particle at a time t. And the dynamics of the particle is described by this equation :

$$ \frac{d}{dt} p_n(t)  = \lambda \Delta p_n(t) $$

Defining one - dimensional lattice translation operator $ E_m = e^{mk} $ with $ km - mk = 1 $ and $\Delta = E_1 + E_{-1} - 2 $ is a lattice laplacian.

So, here are my questions:

1. What is the one-dimensional lattice translation operator ? I think this one is a term from statistical physics, can you give me a simple explanation or a reference ?
2. What is the lattice laplacian ? Is it similar to discrete laplacian ? Could you give me a reference for this one ?
3. Is it possible to solve this equation analytically ?

Oh, all of this equation is about random walk with a boundary (random walk of a particle)

Thanks

Comment: Is $\large n$ a lattice site ?.

Comment: yes, n is the number of particle, or I believe is a lattice site. (n-th particle = n-th lattice)

Answer (score 0):

Write $\large p_{n}\left(t\right) \equiv p_{n}{\rm e}^{-\gamma\mu t\,/a^{2}}$.
$\large a$ is a lattice constant. Then you get
$\large -\left(\mu/a^{2}\right)p_{n} = \Delta p_{n}$. $\large\tt Assuming$ that $n$ is a lattice site index, you'll get

$$
-\,{\mu \over a^{2}}p_{n} = {p_{n + 1} + p_{n -1} - 2p_{n} \over a^{2}} 
$$

or/and
$$
p_{n + 1} + \left(\mu - 2\right)p_{n} + p_{n -1} = 0 
$$

Solutions look like $\large \propto \beta^{n}$.

Comment: Yes, but how about the $ E_m = e^{mk} $ operator defined above ? Because the lattice laplacian here is defined as $ \Delta = E_1 + E_{-1} -2 $. Is it save just to write them as $ p_{n+1} + p_{n-1} - 2p_n $ ?

Answer (score 0):

The following relates to question 2 from the list of 3.

I have worked out a formula for the effect of a discretized Laplacian in one spatial dimension ($\nabla^2_{1D,Discrete}$ or simply $\nabla^2_d$), operating on a function, $\tilde{f}$, whose domain is a discrete set of $x_n$, where the $x_n$ have a distance apart of $a$.

The expression obtained is
$$\nabla^2_d\tilde{f}(x_{n}) = \frac{  \tilde{f}(x_{n+1})+\tilde{f}(x_{n-1})-2\tilde{f}(x_{n})}{a^2}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

the right hand side of (1), is very like

$$ \frac{  p_{n+1}+p_{n-1}-2p_{n}}{a^2}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

The derivation of (1) is pretty straightforward except it  does use both of the following approximations to the derivative

$$\frac{df}{dx}    = \frac{  f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}    = \frac{ f(x)- f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(4)$$

In the derivation (4) is first used to approximate the derivative of a continuous function $f(x)$, then (3) is used to approximate the derivative of the derivative.We find approximately ,  on a continuous domain

$$\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}    = \frac{  f(x+\Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x)-2f(x)}{(\Delta x)^2}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(5)$$

Using (5) on a discrete domain for the function $\tilde{f}$ with $x=x_n$ and $\Delta x=a$ leads to (1).